# Apigee error creating notifier for Android

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apigee

I followed the proper steps at

http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/creating-notifiers

After registering with GCM for an Android API key.  If I do my own "push" notifications my API key works fine, but when trying to register a new Android notifier with the Apigee console it returns:

"Error creating notifiertrue"

As an error pop.  I have tried renaming the notifier and creating/verifying my API keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the name you're giving the notifier?

Comment: tib-Android-Dev, my tib-apple-Dev registers fine

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason the notifiers only seem to work if they're `apple` or `android` respectively. Try re-creating it and naming it just `android`.

Comment: still getting the same issue, wish the error message was a bit more descriptive haha

Comment: yeah... no kidding. Check your javascript console in your browser when creating it and see if that gives you any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect ticket open about this problem.  I have followed up with Engineering, asking them to prioritize this issue.

Comment: thank you Mike, currently still broken sadly, but hopefully it will be fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

Seems something have changed on the Google side and the Apigee docs needs update.

In any case, create a *Server Key*, not an Android Key, for the Notifier.

Note there are issues on the Google console where when creating the key it assign an incorrect date; press "regenerate key" to get a good key. Use that one the Apigee console.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

After a while I decided to **remove** the **IP** provided from Apigee in the Google Developers Console (APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Public API access -> Edit allowed IPs)

After that I could just add the notifier in the Apigee Control Panel as described in the docs.

The IP in the docs is probably outdated but I could not find any other.